# Avoiding pybind11 lifecycle issues

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am writing ReST api requests in Python. These requests are called from and delivered to C++ (Qt) using pybind11. The desired functionality is performing as expected, yet I receive the following warning when executing my script multiple times:

```
context.c:55: warning: mpd_setminalloc: ignoring request to set MPD_MINALLOC a second time
```

I was able to narrow down the origin of the warning to the import of the python `requests` package, which is called from within my script.

Here is a minimum example of how script execution looks like from C++:

```
// member of MyWidget
void callMyPythonScript()
{
    py::scoped_interpreter guard{};
    py::module sys = py::module::import("sys");
    auto locals = py::dict("my_scripts"_a="/path/to/my/python-scripts");
    py::exec(R"(
        import sys
        sys.path.insert(0, '{my_scripts}'.format(**locals()))
    )", py::globals(), locals);

    py::module my_script = py::module::import("my_script");
}
```

The content of `my_script.py` is this one-liner:

```
import requests
```

`callMyPythonScript` is connected to the a button press on the C++ side, using Qt signal slot architecture:

```
connect(button_, &QPushButton::clicked,
        this, &MyWidget::callPythonCode);
```

I did not receive the warning with any packages other than `requests`.

Going by the [pybind11 docs](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/embedding.html) I might already have an answer for all of this:

> Modules created with pybind11 can be safely re-initialized after the interpreter has been restarted. However, this may not apply to third-party extension modules. The issue is that Python itself cannot completely unload extension modules and there are several caveats with regard to interpreter restarting. In short, not all memory may be freed, either due to Python reference cycles or user-created global data.

Still, establishing the aforementioned architecture without worries of memory issues would be what I am looking for. Can anyone here suggest a workflow to fix this? Maybe a CPython based sub-interpreter implementation?

EDIT: Along @jdehesa's comment, I have been checking out the C Api for Python. I generally got the impression, that I would be able to solve my issue with it. But as many other resources on the web already claim, this approach seems like an entirely different beast to tame, when compared with pybind11. Even the pybind11 docs state that one should take good care when mixing in C Api functionality.

For now, I am intending to abandon the Python for request handling entirely and will move the respective features back into C++.

In case anyone would want to offer hands on support, feel free to reach out. I am still curious towards a solution and will share any results with the community at SO.

Comment: You can create multiple Python sub-interpreters from the C API, see [Sub-interpreter support](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#sub-interpreter-support). At some point in the near future these will be brought to the standard Python library, see [PEP 554 -- Multiple Interpreters in the Stdlib](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0554/). I don't know if these would solve your problem, or how you would use it in your case.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look. I hope I don't have to mix in too much plain C API code. If I end up working something out that way, I'll make sure to post it here.